# Is it bad practice to include php files that are basically html?

Tags: php, html

Basically I have some pages that I built for a website and all have the same layout. I was thinking that it is a waste to include all the code that is the same in all the files (wasted bandwidth, waste of time and so on). At first I thought about using frames but I didn't like them very much... I won't give up on them, I just started reading about them but anyway the solution that I really liked and felt like it fit me was I wrote an html file with all the basic layout that is present in every page and then I just wrote a php script in the main area as it is (the part of the page that differs) and depending on the $_GET[] value I include_once("page.php") where that file basically has html code and a little bit of php for some dynamic content that has to do with a database on the server. So it looks like this

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- css and jquery file -->
</head>

<body>
<div id='title'>
</div>

<div id='navigation'>
</div>

<div id='content' style='float:left'>
    <?php 
         switch($_GET['id']) {
               case '1': include_once('./pages/1.php');
               case '2': include_once('./pages/2.php');
               .......
         }
    ?>
</div>

<div id='sidelinks'>
</div>

<div id='footer'>
</div>

<!-- various javascript files for events -->

</body>
</html>
```

However I am just a few months into php and though I read about include I am still not sure if it is bad practice, has any problems or dangers

Comment: Hell no, I don't see a problem. See [require()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) if the loading of these external pages is vital.

Answer (score 7):

That's ok and very normal. PHP includes can make managing common content across pages a simple process and thus make site maintenance easier. That's a good thing.

Common examples include:

- Headers
- Footers
- Site Navigation

Answer (score 2):

As [John Conde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/250259/john-conde) said it's perfectly OK. I would enhance your script a little:

```
// use an array that holds your pages
$pages = array();
$pages[] = array(
    'title' => 'Startpage',
    'metaDescription' => 'Meta Description',
    'include' => './pages/1.php',
    // etc.
);
$pages[404] = array(
    'title' => '404',
    'metaDescription' => 'Meta Description',
    'include' => './pages/1.php',
    // etc.
);

$request = 0;
```

Than you can check:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) {
    $request = ( count($pages) > intval($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 404 );
}

if (404 == $request) {
    // send 404 headers
}
```

And afterwards you can use: `print $pages[$request]['title'];` to display an individual page title and you can include the requested file using `require $pages[$request]['include'];` and so on.

This is just written by heart - not tested and it could simply be improved. It's just an idea to go a little further.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already did something like that but I didn't think to have special management for errors. I defaulted to the index but I think it's better to check everything. I will take you on your advise

Answer (score 0):

It's OK with the way you are going. The only thing you should think about is how to handle HTTP 404 error in case when someone gives incorrect page id.

Answer (score 0):

1- You must prevent any error in your page.

2- In your place I do not use `switch`

```
<?php

$pageid   = $_GET['id'];
$errormsg = '';

if($pageid)
{
    $file_to_call = './pages/' . $pageid . '.php';
    if(is_file($file_to_call))
    {
        include_once($file_to_call);
    }
    else
    {
        $errormsg = "YOUR MESSAGE ERROR";
    }
}
else
{
    $errormsg = "YOUR ANOTHER MESSAGE ERROR";
}
echo $errormsg;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it (by ID number rather than passing a filename) is OK, safer still would be to use file_get_contents, that way you're not importing a file as if it were some code.

Comment: what is the difference between include_once and file_get_contents

Comment: As I understand it, **include** is saying "*make this file part of yourself*", it could be data, it could be executable code (bad for security if this happens when you don't want/need it), **file_get_contents** is saying "read this file into a string variable". There is a security warning on the php manual about using **include** when you don't need to: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php